# Ember - What data types can I pass as arguments into a Glimmer Component?

Tags: ember.js

From another template, I can pass arguments to a component, such as:

```
<MyComponent @arg1="String" />
```

I know I could also pass another named object from the template's JS file, but I don't mean to ask about this.

My question is, what different data types can be passed in from the template, as a String was in the line above. Can I pass in booleans? What about an array of strings? And any special syntax for doing so?

Could I for example use {{each}} to loop through an array argument? I guess the alternative's would be either to process through JS, or perhaps work with {{yeild}}. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any primitive, object, or function (which I think is everything in JS) and there are good reasons for doing each of these.

Sometimes special helpers are needed to create them:

`@obj={{hash name='Zoey')}}`

`@bll={{true}}`

`@arr={{array 1 2 3}}`

A function would have to come from somewhere else, though there are helpers like [ember-simple-set-helper](https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-simple-set-helper) that let you build it in the template

`@fnc={{set this.isAwesome true}}`

Comment: `array` is [part of the framework](http://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.17/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods?anchor=array).

Comment: Thanks @Lux! Fixed.